# Kendo Mobile UI Accordian

Tags: kendo-mobile

Hello all I want to implement accordian like functionality in kendo mobile but I am not getting any solution for that as it does not provide accordian.
Help me by giving any other option.
The data in my opening div is dynamic(the portion which is opened when we click on any row of option)

```
option1
option2
option3
```

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI does not provide a widget for this. You can easily do this with CSS3. [Here is an example](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-content-accordion/)